# Add variable in between do_shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm using redux frmaework for my theme option panel. & I'm using meta slider for my homepage. I used this shortcode in my frontpage template to show the slider:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id=21]'); ?>
```

but I want to change the id from my option panel, so I don't have to edit my template each time I replaced the slider with a new one. I've created a field for that in my redux config page. Now I can use this code:

```
<?php echo $redux_demo['mslider-id']; ?>
```

but I don't know how can I add this to my first code. I want to replace the id number "21", with this 2nd code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather pass the variable to the `id` attribute inside the shortcode. You can even decide to remove the `id` attribute inside the shortcode and make it a static value that you pass to your custom query

For examples and more info about how shortcodes operate, check out the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already visited, but I'm not a pro in php & still learning. so I didn't find my solution.

Comment: Post the code to your shortcode. File an edit to your question

Comment: thanks, but I already solved it. created a variable & passed it, like you suggest before. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help, or did you already use this solution?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id=' . $redux_demo['mslider-id']; . ']'); ?>
```